# Is the syntax of the right expression dependent on the type of the left value?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

Following the tutorial from Kotlin Koans I have met a task about Nullable Types.

This code is accepted by the compiler as correct:

```
fun sendMessageToClient(
        client: Client?, message: String?, mailer: Mailer
) {
    val email = client?.personalInfo?.email;
    if(email != null && message!=null)
    mailer.sendMessage(email, message);
}

class Client(val personalInfo: PersonalInfo?)
class PersonalInfo(val email: String?)
interface Mailer {
    fun sendMessage(email: String, message: String)
}
```

If I change only one word `val` to `String`:

```
fun sendMessageToClient(
        client: Client?, message: String?, mailer: Mailer
) {
      // here is the change
    String email = client?.personalInfo?.email;
    if(email != null && message!=null)
    mailer.sendMessage(email, message);
}

class Client(val personalInfo: PersonalInfo?)
class PersonalInfo(val email: String?)
interface Mailer {
    fun sendMessage(email: String, message: String)
}
```

the line under the comment is marked by the compiler as having 4 same errors "Expecting an element", placed at `=`, both `?.` and `;`.

If I remove `val` in both Client and PersonalInfo class descriptions, nothing changes.

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String email = client?.personalInfo?.email` is not a valid Kotlin syntax. It's a Java syntax.

If you'd like to specify the type, you do it after the variable name:

```
val email: String = client?.personalInfo?.email
```

The error is just telling you that compiler is not able to even parse the code.

Comment: I see. Only there should be `String?,` without the question mark, it is an error, too.